# Hölder continuous implying the rate of convergence of the Cesàro mean

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $f$ be a periodic function which is Hölder continuous of order $0<\alpha<1$

And $\sigma_nf$ be its $n^{th}$ Cesàro mean. Let $ \|f \|=\|f\|_\infty+\sup_{x \neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}$.

The I have to show that $\|\sigma_nf-f\|_{\infty} \leq C\|f\|n^{-\alpha}$ for all natural number $n$ and a constant $C$.

I tried to use the convolution and the Fejér kernel to show this inequality but failed in every attempt and it is unbearably frustrating…

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: What is the Cesaro mean of a function (rather than a sequence)?

Comment: $\sigma_nf=(S_0f+...+S_nf)/(n+1)$ where $S_nf$ is the $n^{th}$ Fourier partial sum of $f$.

Comment: You gave the definition of $||f||$  wrong (what you wrote is right for $\alpha=1$).

Comment: Oops. I will correct it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $K_n$ is the Fejer kernel then $\frac1{2\pi}\int K_n=1$, so for example
$$\sigma_nf(0)-f(0)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi(f(t)-f(0))K_n(t)\,dt.$$Now use the fact that $|f(t)-f(0)|\le c|t|^\alpha$...

**Edit:** So we need to show that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi|t|^\alpha K_n(t)\,dt\le c n^{-\alpha}.$$

The OP says he got this far and doubts that $K_n$ is nice enough to satisfy this inequality. The inequality is true, and it can be proved with no big inspiration, just fairly straightforward inequalities.

But it's a slight pain. This sort of thing is often simpler on the line instead of the circle, because formulas on the circle that are sort of analogous to dilations become actual dilations on the line.

So for example the corresponding gizmo on the line would be $k_n$, where $$k_n(t)=nk(nt)$$and $k\in L^1$. In this context we have by a simple change of variable $$\int |t|^\alpha k_n(t)=\int |t|^\alpha nk(nt)=\int(|t|/n)^\alpha)k(t)=cn^{-\alpha}.$$

Now on the circle it doesn't quite work like that, since $K_n(t)\ne nK(nt)$. But $K_n(t)$ is at least analogous to $nK(nt)$, close enough to make it all work. Note first that if $t\in[-\pi,\pi]$ then $|\sin(t/2)|\ge c|t|$. So
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi|t|^\alpha K_n(t)\le c\int_{-\pi}^\pi |t|^\alpha n\frac{\sin^2(nt/2)}{(nt)^2},$$and you can use the change of variable  on that last integral.

Comment: This is what I already tried... $K_n$ does not seem to be good enough to give the right decay...

Comment: Or is there some magic way I have not figured out?

Comment: @Keith See edit.

Comment: Now I see it. But one more thing. According to you, I can replace $\| f \|$ with just $\sup_{x \neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's the right norm. Glad you asked about the "small $t$" thing: When I wrote the above I thought it was going to be one of those things where one argument works for $|t|<\delta$ and a simpler argument works for larger $t$. But thinking about the details in order to answer your question I saw no: In fact the relevant inequality holds on $[-\pi,\pi]$. See edit (There's a reason I  used that interval instead of some other interval of length $2\pi$.)

Comment: Thanks so much. One last thing: I think we have to careful about the definition of $G_n$ because the change of variables dilate the interval on which we integrate. What I think is that we have to set $G_n=0$ outside the interval $[ -\pi, \pi]$. If what I think is right, then I am settled.

Comment: The reason we have to be a little careful about $G_n$ is it's not periodic. I should say it's defined as I did _on_ the  interval $[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: Right. $G_n$ is defined as you did on the specific interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ and zero outside the interval, so it is not periodic.

Comment: So let's just forget $G_n$. See edit...

Comment: @Keith The only bad $1/2$ I can find has to be there, it was just in the wrong place. Who the heck knows the formula for $K_n$? Not me, evidently. Looks right now?

Comment: Yes. I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: Actually you _have_ thanked me enough...

Comment: Indeed, on $[-\pi,\pi]$, $|\sin(t/2)|\ge\underset{\uparrow\\c}{\frac1\pi}|t|$, and it seems the last inequality should be $$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi|t|^\alpha K_n(t)\color{#C00}{\le}\overset{1/c^2\\\,\downarrow}{\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |t|^\alpha n\frac{\sin^2(nt/2)}{(nt)^2} $$ Otherwise, this looks good. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn The value of that constant clearly doesn't matter. You seem to feel that at a certain spot I should  have written $1/c^2$ instead of $c$.  Same thing, given the standard convention that the value of "$c$" may change from appearance to appearance...

Comment: The constant is not so important, although the fact the same constant variable is used in two places with different meaning might be confusing to some. However, the sense of the inequality is fairly important.

Comment: @robjohn Oh dear. I had the impression you were correcting my $c$ to $1/c^2$, didn't notice you'd also changed the direction of the inequality in your comment. Yes, I suppose if we're being picky the difference between $\ge$ and $\le$ may matter somewhat. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The proof for the line can be applied to the circle using inequality $(4)$.

---

**Preliminary Inequalities for $\boldsymbol{0\lt x\lt\frac\pi2}$**

**Inequality $\bf{1}$:**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)\right)\tag{1b}\\
&\ge\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4^k}\right)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: Induction, $\frac{\sin(x)}{2\sin(x/2)}=\cos(x/2)$, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2^n\sin\left(x/2^n\right)=x$
$\text{(1b)}$: $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)\vphantom{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}}$
$\phantom{\text{b}}\text{(1)}$: $\sin^2(x)\le x^2$

**Inequality $\bf{2}$:**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\tan(x)}{x}
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{1-\tan^2\left(x/2^k\right)}\tag{2a}\\
&\ge\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{1-\frac{x^2}{4^k}}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: Induction, $\frac{\tan(x)}{2\tan(x/2)}=\frac1{1-\tan^2(x/2)}$, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2^n\tan\left(x/2^n\right)=x$
$\phantom{\text{a}}\text{(2)}$: $\tan^2(x)\ge x^2$

**Inequality $\bf{3}$:**

Multiplying inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$
\frac{\sin^2(x)\tan(x)}{x^3}\ge1\tag3
$$
**Inequality $\bf{4}$:**

Inequality $(3)$ implies that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac1{\sin^2(x)}-\frac1{x^2}\right)
&=\frac2{x^3}-\frac{2\cos(x)}{\sin^3(x)}\tag{4a}\\
&\ge0\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\frac1{\sin^2(x)}-\frac1{x^2}$ is increasing, it attains its maximum on $\left(0,\frac\pi2\right]$ at $\frac\pi2$. Therefore,
$$
\frac1{\sin^2(x)}-\frac1{x^2}\le1-\frac4{\pi^2}\tag4
$$

---

**Hölder Bound on the Kernel**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{\sin^2(\pi nx)}{n\sin^2(\pi x)}|x|^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\sin^2(\pi nx)}{n\sin^2(\pi x)}x^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5a}\\
&=2n^{-\alpha-2}\int_0^{n/2}\frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{\sin^2(\pi x/n)}x^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5b}\\
&\le\frac2{\pi^2}n^{-\alpha}\int_0^{n/2}\frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{x^{2-\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}x+\left(1-\frac4{\pi^2}\right)\frac{2^{-\alpha}}{1+\alpha}n^{-1}\tag{5c}\\
&\le\frac2{\pi^2}n^{-\alpha}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{1+\alpha}+\frac1{1-\alpha}\right)+\left(1-\frac4{\pi^2}\right)\frac{2^{-\alpha}}{1+\alpha}n^{-1}\tag{5d}\\[6pt]
&=O\!\left(n^{-\alpha}\right)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: apply symmetry
$\text{(5b)}$: substitute $x\mapsto x/n$
$\text{(5c)}$: apply $(4)$ and evaluate the integral of $x^\alpha$
$\text{(5d)}$: estimate the integral on $[0,1]$, where $\sin^2(\pi x)\le\pi^2x^2$,
$\phantom{\text{(5d):}}$ and on $[1,\infty]$, where $\sin^2(\pi x)\le1$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps here is another doable proof: Let's denote $$[f]_{C^{\alpha}}:=\sup_{x\neq y}\dfrac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}},$$ and $$\|f\|_{C^{\alpha}}:=\|f\|_{\infty}+[f]_{C^{\alpha}}.$$

The Fejer Kernel has the form $$K_{n}(x):=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{n+1}\Big(\dfrac{\sin\frac{n+1}{2}x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\Big)^{2}.$$

Firstly, $\sin n\alpha\leq n\sin\alpha$, so $$(1)\ \ |K_{n}(x)|=\dfrac{1}{2\pi(n+1)}\dfrac{|\sin\frac{n+1}{2}x|^{2}}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}\leq\dfrac{1}{2\pi(n+1)}(n+1)^{2}\dfrac{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}=\dfrac{n+1}{2\pi}.$$

On the other hand, note that $$|\sin\frac{x}{2}|>\dfrac{|x|}{\pi}>\dfrac{|x|}{2\pi}\ \text{for}\ 0<|x|<\pi,$$ which implies that $$(2)\ \ |K_{n}(x)|=\dfrac{1}{2\pi(n+1)}\dfrac{|\sin\frac{n+1}{2}x|^{2}}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}\leq\dfrac{1}{2\pi(n+1)}\dfrac{1}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}\leq\dfrac{2\pi}{(n+1)x^{2}}.$$

Now, recall that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}K_{n}(y)dy=1$, then we compute as follows:
\begin{align*}
|\sigma_{n}(f)(x)-f(x)|&=|(K_{n}*f)(x)-f(x)|\\
&=|(f*K_{n})(x)-f(x)|\ \text{by the commutative of convolution}\\
&=\Big|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-y)K_{n}(y)dy-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)K_{n}(y)dy\Big|\ \text{by what we just recalled}\\
&\leq\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x-y)-f(x)|\cdot |K_{n}(y)|dy\\
&\leq\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[f]_{\alpha}|y|^{\alpha}\cdot|K_{n}(y)|dy\\
&=[f]_{\alpha}\int_{|y|<\frac{\pi}{n+1}}|y|^{\alpha}|K_{n}(y)|dy+[f]_{\alpha}\int_{\frac{\pi}{n+1}\leq|y|\leq\pi} |y|^{\alpha}|K_{n}(y)|dy\\
&\leq\dfrac{[f]_{\alpha}(n+1)}{2\pi}\int_{|y|<\frac{\pi}{n+1}}|y|^{\alpha}dy+\dfrac{2\pi[f]_{\alpha}}{(n+1)}\int_{\frac{\pi}{n+1}\leq|y|\leq\pi}|y|^{\alpha}\cdot y^{-2}dy,
\end{align*}
where the last inequality was obtained by imposing the inequality $(1)$ to the first term and the inequality $(2)$ to the second term.

Now, do the normal integral, and then we will have 
\begin{align*}
|\sigma_{n}(f)(x)-f(x)|&\leq\dfrac{[f]_{\alpha}(n+1)}{2\pi}\cdot\dfrac{2}{\alpha+1}\cdot\dfrac{\pi^{\alpha+1}}{(n+1)^{\alpha+1}}+\dfrac{2\pi[f]_{\alpha}}{(n+1)}\cdot\dfrac{2}{\alpha-1}\Big(\pi^{\alpha-1}-\Big(\dfrac{\pi}{n+1}\Big)^{\alpha-1}\Big)\\
&=\dfrac{[f]_{\alpha}\pi^{\alpha}}{(\alpha+1)(n+1)^{\alpha}}+\dfrac{4\pi^{\alpha}[f]_{\alpha}}{(n+1)(\alpha-1)}-\dfrac{4\pi^{\alpha}[f]_{\alpha}}{(n+1)^{\alpha}(\alpha-1)}\ \ (*).
\end{align*}

Note that the second term is $\leq 0$ since $\alpha<1\implies (\alpha-1)<0$ and all other terms are $\geq 0$.

Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
(*)&\leq \dfrac{[f]_{\alpha}\pi^{\alpha}}{(\alpha+1)(n+1)^{\alpha}}-\dfrac{4\pi^{\alpha}[f]_{\alpha}}{(n+1)^{\alpha}(\alpha-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{[f]_{\alpha}}{(n+1)^{\alpha}}\Big(\dfrac{\pi^{\alpha}}{\alpha+1}-\dfrac{4\pi^{\alpha}}{\alpha-1}\Big).
\end{align*}

Thus, define $C_{\alpha}:=\Big(\dfrac{\pi^{\alpha}}{\alpha+1}-\dfrac{4\pi^{\alpha}}{\alpha-1}\Big)$ and then we are able to conclude that $$|\sigma_{n}(f)(x)-f(x)|\leq \dfrac{C_{\alpha}[f]_{\alpha}}{(n+1)^{\alpha}}\leq \dfrac{C_{\alpha}[f]_{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}}.$$

In particular, notice that $C_{\alpha}\geq 0$, since $(\alpha-1)<0$ so $-\dfrac{4\pi^{\alpha}}{(\alpha-1)}>0$.

Hence, we can further write: $$|\sigma_{n}(f)(x)-f(x)|\leq \dfrac{C_{\alpha}[f]_{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}}\leq\dfrac{C_{\alpha}([f]_{\alpha}+|f(x)|)}{n^{\alpha}},$$ since $|f(x)|\geq 0$.

Now, taking $\sup$ on the both side of the inequality over all $x$, we obtain the desired inequality that $$\|\sigma_{n}(f)-f\|_{\infty}\leq\dfrac{C_{\alpha}([f]_{\alpha}+\|f\|_{\infty})}{n^{\alpha}}=\dfrac{C_{\alpha}\|f\|_{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}}.$$